# C#: data-binding objects such as DataGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

C#: if you bind a DataGrid object to a List object and set the columns to show properties of List's objects, will the DataGrid update when the data-object does?

Is it advisable to data-bind DataGrids?  Isn't it better for the programmer to control this process themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, DataGrid will not update when the data-object does. If you want such behavior you need to implement IBindingList or use [BindingList class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) (or DataTable).